50 V pulse generator with large resistive load
I am trying to design a 0-50 V pulse generator to be placed across a 100 Ω-1 kΩ load. As such this generator must be able to provide up to 500 mA of current. The catch is that fall times must be 5 ns at maximum and pulse width must be variable from 100 ns to dc. Rise times don't matter as much.
Currently I am using the LMG1020 with a PWM signal to create my variable pulse width. This drives a GanFET (EPC2001C) which pulls the load down.
The issue is due to the size of the load the fall time greatly suffers as the resistor slows charge equalising across it.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I have tried many other ideas such as adding a FET and/or resistors other configurations such as the one below.

simulate this circuit
In general the issues faced are either very high power dissipation outside of the device, very bad fall times or an inability to have long pulse widths due to capacitive discharge.
Any advice or design changes would be very useful and greatly appreciated!

Have you attempted a sanity check by computing the capacitance using $C\le\frac{I,\cdot, \Delta t}{\Delta V}$? Not much.

What is M3 supposed to do in your second schematic?

M3 is meant to pull the other end of R1 down to ground. Was much faster pulling both down instead of waiting for charge to bring the drain of R1 up.

Is the load a laser diode or a simple resistor next to the driver or something else with ESL= 0.5nH/mm?  Is the load single-ended with common ground or differential?  Pls remove 1ohm load

How much overshoot and settling time can you tolerate?   (see what I mean about specs?)

The critical parameter for this purpose is the MOSFET's output capacitance Coss; every time the FET turns off, the output capacitance needs to be charged up to the supply voltage through the load.
The simple solution is to choose a MOSFET with low Coss. The EPC2001C has pretty low Coss for its ratings, but you can get much lower Coss if you use a smaller FET more appropriate to your use case. Consider the DMN6075S, for instance, with Coss less than a tenth that of the EPC2001C. As a bonus, it's also less than a twentieth the price (I don't know why you're using a GaN device for this).
The better solution is to drive the load with a half bridge instead of a single device. This way, you can charge the MOSFET's output capacitance through another MOSFET instead of through your load, like so:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The two gate drivers here can be the two channels of a dual-channel driver, which may add other nice features like dead time (shoot-through prevention). You will need an isolated power supply for the high-side gate driver; there are very cheap plug-and-play modules available from various companies that will do the job.
Of course, using low-Coss transistors is still a good idea. The EPC2001C is massive overkill for what you're doing; look at cheaper and smaller alternatives.
Don't forget to account for the propagation delay of whatever you use to invert your control pulse. Since you're doing things on nanosecond scales, that can be significant. In my experience, you can usually get good enough matching between a 74LVC1G14 inverter and a 74LVC1G17 non-inverting buffer from the same manufacturer.

Here's a more complete example of how I would personally do this, because I felt like fleshing it out:

simulate this circuit
This assumes you only have a +5 V supply available. If there's also a +12 V supply, you can eliminate one of the ROE-0512S power modules. If there's only a 3.3 V supply available and no 5 V one, you'd have to use a different power module that can take 3 V input. (The MAX2270x is fine running on 3.3 V input-side power, though.)
Rg can be 0 Ω for the fastest possible switching time, if desired and if that doesn't give too much ringing. Using the Miller clamp pin is probably unnecessary here, but it doesn't hurt. I've left out the bypass capacitors that the gate drivers need to avoid cluttering the schematic; don't forget those!

Thanks for your help! I modelled the design on a laser driver so the Gan was a remnant of that. The reason I didn't go for this design is the problem on running the high side. As the source voltage of M2 changes so much and so quickly it was difficult finding an optocoupler or other system to bring the logic at CLK1 up to 50V. Any recommendations? Also thanks for your Fet choice advice.

@Architectoid There are purpose-designed isolated gate drivers specifically for this, such as the MAX2270x or the UCC21521. You just need to pair them with a suitable isolated power supply, such as Recom's ROE or R1SE series or Murata's NMA or MGJ series. || Note that it's GaN, not gan or Gan. The chemical symbols for gallium (Ga) and nitrogen (N).

The spec that matters, incidentally, is the common-mode transient immunity, or CMTI, which refers to the fastest such voltage swing the isolator is guaranteed to withstand without any spurious output changes.

Your DMN6075S FET choice has mean RdsOn of 0.1 Ohms "meaning" it will dissipate 10% of the 1 Ohm load just at DC.    Isn't that a red flag?  Why did you only consider Coss?

@D.A.S. The load was stated to be between 100 Ω and 1 kΩ; 1 Ω was never mentioned. I believe the 1 Ω load in the schematic there was the asker's attempt to compensate for Coss by providing a lower-resistance path to charge it; this has the issue they mentioned that it results in excessive power being wasted. Better to use a half-bridge and switch the additional path off, rather than have it always there.

Yes the question needs to be edited to have clear specs.

Would the above design work better if we replaced the pull up n_channel FET with a p_mos, perhaps SI7113ADN-T1-GE3. Would remove the need for the isolating supply and would greatly reduce the overall area cost on the board. Rise time may be hurt a bit but fall time (at least by my sims) should stay relatively constant.
This would be especially useful as I need multiple of these circuits on the board.

@Architectoid You could. I wouldn't say it would work better, but it would still work. It would be difficult to drive it in a way that gets good rise time, but if fall time is all that matters to you that's fine. Remember that you can't just apply 0 V to the gate of a PMOS with its source at 50 V. Use a zener and resistor to keep the gate-to-source voltage within its ratings; few FETs can survive more than about -30 V on their gate, and most aren't designed for more than -10 or -15 V.

Assuming the FET is a perfect switch...
When the switch closes, the time constant of the current in the 1kohm resistor is around 10 microsec's driven largely by the 1 ohm resistor and the capacitor. I understand that's what you're calling the rise time.
And, the initial current spike in the FET is 50A limited only by the 1 ohm resistor and any resistance of the capacitor - as we are neglecting the FET resistance for now. It's appropriate to say that this event "discharges" the capacitor.
When the switch opens, the time constant of the current in the 1kohm resistor is around 10 milliseconds driven largely by the 1kohm resistor and the capacitor. I understand that's what you're calling the fall time.  So, yes that's a lot slower in comparison. And this is what you want to speed up.
I dare not ask what the purpose of the capacitor might be as it's a given.
So, it seems the task is to charge the capacitor quicker while it's connected to the load or to disconnect it and then charge it more slowly while there's no current in the 1k ohm resistor.  You might put a FET in series with the capacitor to OPEN / turn off when the pulse generating FET OPENS and then slowly turn it back on in time for the next pulse.  Maybe an RC to the gate would do it. You can adjust the added capacitor value and the 2 added resistor values to suit the needs.
